# Can you detect if an ssh connection closed?

Tags: linux, ssh

I have 2 Linux systems. One system will be constantly connected to the other machine via SSH.

If it detects that the connection closed, it will connect via ssh again, and run a specific command.

Is this even possible or not?

I saw cronjob, but that does not detect ssh closed connections or similar.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details how the SSH connection is used. How do you start it? Do you run commands via this connection? Dou you use any of the tunneling options? Please add all details to your question, don't use comments for this purpose.

Comment: Have a look at autossh.

Comment: I'll second this. Take a look at [`autossh`](http://www.debianadmin.com/autossh-automatically-restart-ssh-sessions-and-tunnels.html).

Comment: A clear »it depends«. There are ways a connection gets closed, that are detectable, like a clean socket.close on the other end or the local interface going down (like the ethernet cable getting unplugged), but other connections can silently die with the socket staying open. You need some heartbeat handshake then to identify the connection was lost.

Comment: The command running on login should get a hangup signal (SIGHUP) when the connection is closed.

Answer (score 2):

Since ssh exits when the connection breaks, you can write a script that starts ssh in an infinite loop, or in a conditional loop which repeats while the exit code of ssh is 255 (an error occurred). This way the script will wait for ssh to exit and if it's due to an error, restart it. Or you can use `autossh`, as Adrian Zaugg suggested. You didn't specify enough details of your setup to get a more specific answer.

Here's a "generalized" example, though it may not work for you due to your specifics:

1. Your server should be set up to accept public key authentication and should have client's public key authorized.
2. The ~/.ssh/config file on your client machine should have a setup for the host you are connecting to, so that your ssh client wouldn't need interaction and would send ping packets to detect disconnection:

> ```
> Host serverhost
> User username
> IdentityFile /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
> ServerAliveInterval 30
> ServerAliveCountMax 2
> ```

The `IdentityFile` setting here is the name of the private key used for authentication, `ServerAliveInterval` is the number of seconds between pings, and `ServerAliveCountMax` is how many unresponded pings will cause ssh to exit. With the setup above, broken connection will be detected after one minute.

3. Your script should be launched only once (or remember its PID and kill the previous instance on relaunch). The script may look like this:

> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> while true ; do
>   ssh serverhost
>   if [ $? -ne 255 ] ; then
>      break
>   fi
> done
> ```

This assumes you have sh shell installed, your private key has no passphrase, you don't want your ssh session in background and don't intend to relaunch the script until you exit your ssh session cleanly. That's a lot of assumptions, so as I said, I need details to answer clearly. Sorry, I don't have time for guessing.

Comment: Could you add one example of such a script?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There are too many different environments for one script, also there are some settings which could prevent detection, that's why I said I need more details. This is supposed to be an answer to the question, not an essay covering all possible cases.